# Best way to simulate typing into a text entry

Tags: javascript, textbox

I'm having trouble with a JavaScript automation. Essentially, what I need to do is set the value of a text field to something specific:

```
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Chewing Gum" value>
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
textboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("input")
textboxes[1].setAttribute("value", "12345")
textboxes[1].value = "12345"
```

Both yield visible results (`.value` causes the visible field to become populated, `.setAttribute` causes the value attribute to become populated in the page source (both of these things occur when normally typing into the field)).

However, the text entry is in a submission form. When pressing submit, the form submits nothing to the next page (so neither of the things changed in `.setAttribute` and `.value` actually effect what's sent to the database, even though both changes occur when typing). I'm not sure how one would accomplish masking input entry in such a way, so I'm not sure how to approach fixing this issue.

I have attempted to use:

```
triggerEvent(document.getElementsByClassName("input"), 'change')
```

to rectify the problem, but that returns false in the console and does not fix the issue.

I'm not sure what other options I have to send value data to the text field, so I can only think to mimic a user actually typing to solve this issue, but I'm also not sure if this is possible in JavaScript (as it would be in Node.js).